# pox controller starting problem

Tags: sudo

When I run

```
/home/habiba/pox/pox.py  forwarding.l2_pairs\info.packet_dump samples.pretty_log.level  --DEBUG
```

The output is:

```
Module not found:forwarding.l2_pairsinfo.packet_dump
```

Comment: What were you expecting?  What exactly is not working?

Comment: I want to configure pox as a listening controller.